# Why is 'this' different things in two different functions?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a problem where `this` isn't what I expect it to be, but I can't figure out why after hours of ripping my hair out. From what I understand `this` should be the same `this` in both functions, but it isn't. This causes my custom select to not update the label when you select something else in the dropdown because `getCurrentOption` always returns `undefined` since it tries to access `.currentOption` from the wrong `this` object.

Can someone explain what is happening here? And how to make it so that I pass the same `this` object to the two functions?

`co-select.html`:

```
<div class="co-select-form-control">
    <label class="co-inset-label" ng-bind="label"></label>
    <ul class="list-reset" ng-class="{'co-select': !label, 'co-select-labeled': label}">
        <li ng-click="co.toggleSelect(this)" class="co-select-option clickable">
            <span ng-bind="co.getCurrentOption(this) || default"></span>
            <ul ng-show="co.isSelectToggled(this)" class="list-reset bg-light co-select-dropdown">
                <li ng-repeat="option in list" ng-if="option !== co.getCurrentOption(this)" 
                        ng-click="co.selectOption(this, option)" ng-bind="option" class="co-select-option"></li>
            </ul>
            <span class="co-select-icon">
                <i class="icon icon-keyboard-arrow-{{co.isSelectToggled(this) ? 'up' : 'down'}}"></i>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

co-select directive:

```
coForms.directive('coSelect', [function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            default: '=',
            list: '=',
            label: '@'
        },
        controller: 'CoFormsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'co',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/components/co-forms/co-select.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    };
}]);
```

The controller:

```
coForms.controller('CoFormsCtrl', [function() {

    var coForms = this;

    /* View functions */
    coForms.toggleSelect = function(select) {
        select.isToggled = !select.isToggled;
    };

    coForms.isSelectToggled = function(select) {
        return select.isToggled ? true : false;
    };

    coForms.selectOption = function(select, option) {
        select.currentOption = option;
        console.log(select);
    };

    coForms.getCurrentOption = function(select) {
        console.log(select);
        return select.currentOption;
    };
}]);
```

The `console.log` from within `coForms.getCurrentOption` shows `this` to be:

[image: image 1]

While the `console.log` from within `coForms.selectOption` shows `this` to be:

[image: image 2]

How I use this directive:

```
<co-select list="['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3']" default="'option 1'"></co-select>
```

Comment: @estus I'm not too used to working with directives, so I'm not 100% clear on how to do it exactly. How would it know "select" is the directive scope? Wouldn't I have to add something to the directive for it to know that?

Comment: Use 'coForms.isToggled' instead of 'select.isToggled'. Also, you shouldn't use two-way binding `list: '='` on anonymous array, use one-way binding instead.

Comment: @estus It's not an anonymous array, I just added that as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because ng-repeat creates a new scope (if i'm correct, it extends the parent scope), your selectOption is called inside ng-repeat so `this` represents that scope.

You shouldn't be using controller functions this way (passing `this` as parameter). You should make a variable "select" in your scope and use that.

This should work (see this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Javqd1zoKbubHEUD2Ea9?p=preview ) :

```
coForms.directive('coSelect', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            default: '=',
            list: '=',
            label: '@'
        },
        controller: 'CoFormsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'co',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/components/co-forms/co-select.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        } 
    };
}]);

coForms.controller('CoFormsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    var coFormsCtrl = this;
    coFormsCtrl.select={
      isToggled: true,
      currentOption:$scope.default
    };

    /* View functions */
    coFormsCtrl.toggleSelect = function() {
        coFormsCtrl.select.isToggled = !coFormsCtrl.select.isToggled;
    };

    coFormsCtrl.isSelectToggled = function() {
        return coFormsCtrl.select.isToggled ? true : false;
    };

    coFormsCtrl.selectOption = function(option) {
        coFormsCtrl.select.currentOption = option;
        console.log(coFormsCtrl.select);
    };

    coFormsCtrl.getCurrentOption = function() {
        console.log(coFormsCtrl.select);
        return coFormsCtrl.select.currentOption;
    };
}]);
```

And the template:

```
<div class="co-select-form-control">
          <label class="co-inset-label" ng-bind="label"></label>
          <ul class="list-reset" ng-class="{'co-select': !label, 'co-select-labeled': label}">
              <li ng-click="co.toggleSelect()" class="co-select-option clickable">
                  <span ng-bind="co.getCurrentOption() || default"></span>
                  <ul ng-show="co.isSelectToggled()" class="list-reset bg-light co-select-dropdown">
                      <li ng-repeat="option in list" ng-if="option !== co.getCurrentOption()" 
                              ng-click="co.selectOption(option)" ng-bind="option" class="co-select-option"></li>
                  </ul>
                  <span class="co-select-icon">
                      <i class="icon icon-keyboard-arrow-{{co.isSelectToggled() ? 'up' : 'down'}}"></i>
                  </span>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Could you show how to do that properly? Because god knows I've tried already without success.

Comment: is there a "select" variable in your parent scope?

Comment: No, I'm creating a lot of select boxes, so I just simply want to pass the select box you click to the controller functions.

Comment: I have edited my answer again (forgot template and fixed an error in the code)

Comment: Now it works, but with an annoying bug, but it's not a part of the question so I'll figure it out :) thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Angular expressions [`this` is a special word](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.7/src/ng/parse.js#L628) and [refers to the scope on which the expression is being evaluated](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.7/src/ng/parse.js#L1439). Since `ng-repeat` creates a new scope, scope inside and outside it will be different.

Using `this` in expressions can be rarely required, and this case isn't an exception.

Comment: How can I make sure that I pass the current select box to the functions? Using 'this' was the only solution I came up with, and it does seem to be awful.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Why exactly do you want to pass anything to controller methods? 'select' there should refer to directive's scope, isn't it?